# Convert string with date text to date format in BIRT table

Tags: birt

I have a Date which I retrieve as a string "Dec 20 2007" from my front end app and insert into a BIRT table.

Since the data type for this field is set as "Type: String" when I convert it to Date the table breaks and no data is visible in the Table.

My ultimate goal is to sort the table by Date.

Any solution to convert the string which is "Dec 20 2004" to date format in BIRT table.

Thanks.

Comment: Your probably going to need to use  java script in a computed column to chop up the string and make it into dates.  Are the dates in your source consistent (i.e. is it always Dec, or is sometimes December and other times 12)?  Can you change the data type to date on your source data set?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I cannot change the data type at the source since it is passed as json. I dont know if it is possible to change it in json but I will have a look at it.
The Format of source date is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Is is very simple, simply create a new empty column in the same table. 
Add a data item with an expression like this:

```
new Date(row["String Date"])
```

http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/36777-convert-string-with-date-text-to-date-format-in-birt-table/

Then you can sort on the new data binding.